# Why it is recommended to store images on remote server?

Tags: image, static, storage, media, remote-server

Sorry for such a question, but I can not find any article on the web with cons on that, I guess it is about async uploading and downloading, but it's just a guess, is there somewhere a detailed info?

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly about specialization, data locality, and concurrency.

Servers that are specialized at serving static content typically do so much faster than dynamic web servers (the web servers are optimized for the specific use-case).

You also have the advantage of storing your content in many zones to achieve better performance (the content is physically closer to the person requesting it), where-as web applications typically should be near its other dependencies, such as databases.

Lastly browsers (for http/1 at least) only allow a fixed number of connections per server, so if your images and api calls are on separate servers, one cannot influence the other in terms of request scheduling.

There are a lot of other reasons I'm sure, but these are just off the top of my head.